# Postgres insert into a specified column in the table from another column in the same table where a primary key exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've dug around on here and accepted answers to other questions haven't worked for me.

I have a table "mytable" defined as such

```sql
create table mytable (
column1 varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
column2 integer,
column3 money
)
```

column3 is all null, and I want to insert column2/1.25 into column3

I've tried these:

```sql
--This gets 23502 "violates not-null constraint"
insert into mytable (column3)
select column2/1.25 from mytable

--This gets 42601 "syntax error near "select""
insert into mytable (column3)
select column2/1.25 from mytable

--Same as above with parentheses, gets the same error
insert into mytable (column3) values
(select column2/1.25 from mytable )

--Error 42601 "syntax error at or near "select""
insert into mytable (column1,column3) values
(select column1, column2/1.25 from mytable)
```

I've tried other slight variations of parentheses, fields in double quotes, but can't figure out why this is throwing me errors. Column1 is a primary key and not nullable, but I'm not trying to insert into that column.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you want to change the value of a column in an existing row, you need to use UPDATE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSERT` adds new rows to the table, which you do not want. To modify existing rows, use `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET column3 = column2 / 1.25;
```

But that is a bad idea for several reasons:

1. Avoid the `money` type. Use something like `numeric(15,2)` instead.
2. Don't keep redundant data in the database unless it is unavoidable for performance reasons.  You could use a view:

   ```
   CREATE VIEW myview AS
   SELECT column1, column2,
          CAST (column2 / 1.25 AS numeric(15,2)) AS column3
   FROM mytable;
   ```
3. If you really want to persist the redundant data, use a generated column:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE mytable
   ADD column3 numeric(15,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (column2 / 1.25) STORED;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT command is used to insert a new row in the table. What you want is to update an existing row.

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update/

```
UPDATE mytable
SET column3 = column2/1.25
```